# How to count the number of matches between two excel files

Tags: excel

Say I have a data set in a worksheet. I want to compare the contents of column A with the contents of column B in another file and put the result in column C. To do this, I could use the formula

```
=IFNA(MATCH($A1,'location/[filename.xlsx]worksheet'!$B:$B,0),FALSE)
```

If I then wanted to count how many matches there were, I need only to count how many entries in column C that contain a numeric value using

```
=COUNT($C:$C)
```

But, what if I wanted to count the number of matches between columns A and B, and each of those columns existed in separate Excel files?

I need cell C1 to calculate the number of matches between entries in column A of file 1 and column B of file 2. Is this possible without editing files 1 or 2? Manually copying the data is one way, but every day has different data, and C2 will need to do the same thing for tomorrow, and C3 for the next day, etc. Manually copying the data would make the workbook size balloon quickly.

Comment: have you explored the COUNTIF function? Count only values that have a matching value in the other spreadsheet?

Comment: I have considered the `COUNTIF` function, but the problem is that I need one cell to count the matches between a column in a second file and another column in a third file. `COUNTIF` can't do that if the data isn't in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create pivot tables in File 3 of the data from File 1 and File 2.  The pivot table for File 2 would have a occurrence count for every entry in the sheet.  The pivot table from File 1 would only have row labels, giving you the unique entries that you are going to be searching for.

beside each pivot label for File 1, enter a formula similar to the following:

```
=+GETPIVOTDATA("Item",PivotTableFile1!$H$7,"Item",A4)
```

Should also do some error checking, which makes the formula:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Item",PivotTableFile1!$H$7,"Item",A4),0)
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't quite understand your formula. I know the `=+` is essentially the Excel version of `x = x+1` in programming, but what are cells A4 and H7? Your solution almost sounds like it might benefit from an array formula. Do you think this is true?

Comment: The plus can actually be removed.  Old habit.

The easiest way to see it is to create the pivot tables.  Then next to one of the values in Pivot 2 you want to look up from Pivot 1, start typing "=" then click one of the data cells from Pivot 1.  It will put the getpivotdata formula in with static references.

Modify the last entry to refer to the field you want from Pivot 2, rather than the static entry.

Comment: $h$7 is the Pivot 1 top left cell.  A4 would be a value in Pivot 2 that I want to lookup from Pivot 1.

Comment: Have a look at the sample here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qul00fw2fz8wajp/GetPivotData%20Example.xlsx